# Picture backcolor changes when using Clipboard.Setimage in C#

Tags: c#

I use Clipboard.SetImage(pictureBox1.Image) for copying picture to another documents, for example to Microsoft Word document. 
It works well, the quality is quite good, but the backcolor of the copied picture is always control blue, even if the backcolor was set to another color.

The situation is very similar when I save the pictureBox1.Image into file. The background will be black or white depending on the file type (bmp, png,...) but not the same as it was set.

I am not professional in c#, but I guess, that the picturebox backcolor and the image are two different things (something like layers in photoshop).

How can I achieve that the backcolor of the copied picture will be the same as set in the picturebox?

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: An image doesn't have a background.  But if it has transparent pixels then what you see depends on what it is rendered on top of.  If you want to avoid that then create a new Bitmap, use Graphics.FromImage(), Graphics.Clear() to set the background color and Graphics.DrawImage() to draw it on that background.

Comment: Dear Hans, Sorry for my late answer. It works. Thank you for your help.